# finding a string in php

Tags: php, string, search

I want to find a string like 'Jobs' in a title. Suppose i have 10 rows in a file.
i.e 
Jobs for Accountant.
Featured Jobs for public Services.
Website Development Jobs in Delhi.
.
.
.
.

How to find jobs keyword in these type of titles?

Comment: What kind of file? This needs more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [strpos](http://php.net/strpos).

```
if(strpos($string, 'Jobs') !== false)
```

Make sure you do it exactly like that, since `if(strpos($string, 'Jobs')` would return 0 if the string started with 'Jobs', which would be casted to the boolean value of 0: false.

Comment: You made the concept for me. I caught the problem Thanks for all.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `strpos`

Just check `if (strpos($string,$search)===0)` and you are good

Comment: It do not detect Jobs in First position.

Comment: @Chorlett if you want to check case-INsensitive use `stripos()`

Answer (score 0):

Use `substr()` to achieve this. Here is the manual php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use strpos. Look [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) for documentation.

it reurns the first occurence of what you are seraching in a string.

you can do:

```
$pos = strpos($string, "jobs")
```

and it returns the offset where it found "jobs".

Then you can $pos to look for further occurences passing it to the function

```
$pos2 = strpos($string, "jobs", $pos+1)
```

if you want to check if it doesn't find a string you must use === because if it finds the string in the first position it returns 0 (that if you just check with == resolves to false)

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions.

Here is a tutorial: http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-regular-expression.html
Or, just google `php regular expressions` for all the info you need.

Comment: I understand your opinion, but I disagree. What use is there in explaining regular expressions here when there are so many good sites and tutorials out there that have done it before. Obviously the guy just needs a pointer in the right direction, which, incidentally, will help him a lot more than a ready-to-copy-and-paste answer that does all work for him but adds nothing to his knowledge or skills.

Comment: OK, good point. I agree with it, as long as the question is meaningful and worth creating a new question for. Imho, an ideal SO question should not be answerable by a simple Google query.